# repo fails with repo: error: "git" failed with exit status 128

Tags: git, gerrit, repo

I have checked the two questions that are somehow related to this one (although none of them use *repo*) and there are no solutions or explanations for this so this is not a double question.

I am trying to use [repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo) and gerrit to download some code. When I do `repo init` with the repositories I got

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
repo: error: "git" failed with exit status 128
```

I am suspecting it has to do with some setting up passwords or permissions, but in this case (repo and gerrit) which settings I should do in order to access it

(More information: I can access the gerrit site, but with a new password, so I suppose some setting there is needed)